# How to create 'Week column' based on another date column?

Tags: date, amazon-redshift, week-number, redash

[image]I have column 'jobstarttimeiso' and I want to create another column for Weeks of the year based on the date. How would I go about doing that? I am using Redash to query from redshift database. Please help! Thank you.[image: ash]

Comment: How do you define "Weeks of the year"? Do you mean a "Week Number", where the first week is Week 1 and the last week is Week 52 or 53? How do you define the "first week" — is it a full week, or does it start on a particular day (eg Sunday or Monday)? Take a look at the [DATE_PART Function - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_PART_function.html). It has a "week" capability.

Comment: Yeah I've tried date part and for some reason it doesn't work. Week 1 - 52

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". Did you receive an error? Or were you just unhappy with the result? How did the result differ from what you were seeking?

Comment: Sorry - I received an error.

Comment: I added a picture above as reference when using date_part

Comment: What is the field type of `jobstarttimeiso`? Is it a timestamp or a varchar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extract function will return a week number e.g.

```
select extract(week from jobstarttimeiso)  as weeknumber
```

In general:

```
EXTRACT ( datepart FROM { TIMESTAMP 'literal' | timestamp } )
```

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_EXTRACT_function.html

alternatively you can also use `to_char()`

```
TO_CHAR (timestamp_expression | numeric_expression , 'format')
```

with the parameter `IYYY` as the format for ISO 8601 week-numbering year (4 or more digits)